# Using Closure Properties to prove Regularity

Tags: regular-language, dfa

Here's a homework problem:

```
Is L_4 Regular?
Let L_4 = L*, where L={0^i1^i | i>=1}.
```

I know L is non-regular and I know that Kleene Star is a closed operation, so my assumption is that L_4 is non-regular.

However my professor provided an example of the above in which `L = {0^p | p is prime}`, which he said was regular by proving that `L*` was equal to `L(000* + e)` by saying each was a subset of one another (e in this case means the empty word).

So his method involved forming a regex of `0^p`, but how I can do that when I essentially have one already?

Comment: {0^p : p prime} is not regular. It's actually context-sensitive.

Comment: Also, it's incorrect to assume that L_4 is not regular just because L is not regular -- closure properties don't work that way!  For example, if we let P be the language of 0^p for prime p, then P* is regular even though P is not.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the first part. We've just started context-free languages and what not.  And yeah, it's a bad assumption...but I've been conditioned to think "closed" -> same type, even for regularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular languages are closed under Kleene star. That is, if language R is regular, so is R*.

But the reasoning doesn't work in the other direction: there are nonregular languages P for which P* is actually regular.

You mentioned one such P in your question:  the set of strings 0^p where p is prime.

It is easy to use the [pumping lemmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma) for regular and context-free languages to show that P is at least context-sensitive.
However, P* is equivalent to the language 0^q, where q is the sum of zero or more primes.
But this is true for q=0 (the empty string) and any q>=2, so P* can be recognized with a 3-state DFA, even though P itself is not regular.

So L being context-free has no bearing on whether your L_4 = L* is regular or not.  If you can construct a DFA that recognizes L_4, as I did for P* above, then clearly it's regular.
In the process of trying to find a DFA that works, you'll probably see some pattern
emerge that can be used as the basis for a pumping argument.  The [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill-Nerode_theorem) is another approach to proving a language non-regular, and is useful if the language lends itself to analysis of prefixes and distinguishing extensions.  If the language can be decomposed into a finite set of equivalence classes under a certain relation, then it can be recognized with a DFA containing that many states.

**Edit**:  For anyone wondering whether OP's example L_4 is regular or not...it's not, which can be proved using the pumping lemma for regular languages.

Assume L_4 is regular, with "pumping length" P. Consider the string w=0<sup>P</sup>1<sup>P</sup>, which is an element of L_4.  We need to decompose it into the form w=xyz,
with |y| >= 1 and |xy| <= P.  Any choice of xy fulfilling these conditions will consist of all zeroes. But then any string w' = xy<sup>n</sup>z with n != 1 will have mismatched counts of 0s and 1s, and therefore cannot be an element of L_4.  So the pumping lemma does not hold, and L_4 cannot be regular.

Comment: I found out that we could use any method to prove the regularity.  Thanks!

Comment: @WAT: Please report back if you come up with a nice proof...don't leave us hanging!

Comment: It looks as though he left you hanging :(

Comment: @g14nfr4nc0 :  Perhaps, but I won't!  :)